# what's the rule to render when linear gradients overlap?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I want to use linear gradient to achieve a cutting corner effect. To cut just one corner is simple:

```css
body {
  background: #eac996;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Then I tried to apply the same code to the other three corners, but failed to achieve the desired effects.

```css
body {
  background: #eac996;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px);
  background:
    -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -moz-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -moz-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px);
  background:
    -o-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -o-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -o-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -o-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

The right way is to avoid the overlap of those linear gradients. As following

```css
body {
  background: #eac996;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px);
  background:
    -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -moz-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -moz-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px);
  background:
    -o-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -o-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -o-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px),
    -o-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px);
  background-position:
    bottom left,
    bottom right,
    top right,
    top left;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

My question is that what's the rule for browser to render when linear gradients overlap? Some links to the spec or further reading about this topic will be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean, what’s the rule? Same as with any other multiple backgrounds I’d say – top to bottom …

Comment: When it comes to multiple background images or gradients (which are 'images' per se), the first declared image/gradient sits on the top, while the last declared one sits at the bottom: https://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: @Terry It's a bit of counter intuitive, isn't it? As in normal case, the latter css property overrides the former one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the layering of multiple gradients, as in the comma-separated values in each declaration, then [the layers are painted front-to-back](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering). It may seem counter-intuitive considering how the [cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order) is defined and [how source-ordered elements with the same stack level stack with one another](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers), but that is just how the background layering order is defined.

But the layering order isn't relevant here, because either way the colored regions of each gradient are all going to overlap one another. The real reason you need to add `background-position` and `background-size` declarations to prevent the gradients from overlapping one another is because [gradients have no intrinsic size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#gradients), and so [they will all scale to cover the entire box by default](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size).